# Version: WebLogic Server 12.2.1.4.0

Tags: jersey, weblogic12c

I am getting below warnings when I start my weblogic server that is deployed with a rest service application that is developed with JaxRS2.0 and Jersey 2.22.2.

```
<Jul 5, 2022 5:47:39,957 PM EDT> <Warning> <JAXRSIntegration> <BEA-2192510> <Cannot add Jersey servlet for application class org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig because ApplicationPath annotation is not set on it.> 
<Jul 5, 2022 5:47:39,960 PM EDT> <Warning> <JAXRSIntegration> <BEA-2192510> <Cannot add Jersey servlet for application class org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$WrappingResourceConfig because ApplicationPath annotation is not set on it.> 
<Jul 5, 2022 5:47:39,961 PM EDT> <Warning> <JAXRSIntegration> <BEA-2192510> <Cannot add Jersey servlet for application class org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig because ApplicationPath annotation is not set on it.>
```

I tried below steps:

1. install jax-rs 2.0 reference library as one of the applications using weblogic Admin console.
2. I have used below lib-ref in my weblogic.xml file that is bundled within WEB-INF

   ```
   <wls:library-ref>
      <library-name>jax-rs</library-name>
      <specification-version>2.0</specification-version>
      <exact-match>false</exact-match>
   </wls:library-ref>
   ```
3. I have my weblogic-applicaiton.xml file with  as below

   ```
   enter <prefer-application-packages>
       <!-- jersey-bundle-*.jar -->
       <package-name>com.sun.jersey.*</package-name>
       <package-name>com.sun.research.ws.wadl.*</package-name>
       <package-name>com.sun.ws.rs.ext.*</package-name>
       <!-- <package-name>org.glassfish.jersey.*</package-name> -->
       <!-- <package-name>org.glassfish.hk2.*</package-name> -->
       <package-name>org.jvnet.hk2.*</package-name>
       <package-name>jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.*</package-name>

       <!-- Jackson-*.jar -->
       <package-name>org.codehaus.jackson.*</package-name>
       <package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.*</package-name>

       <!-- jettison-*.jar -->
       <package-name>org.codehaus.jettison.*</package-name>

       <!-- jsr311*.jar -->
       <package-name>javax.ws.rs.*</package-name>

       <!-- asm.jar -->
       <package-name>org.objectweb.asm.*</package-name>
   </prefer-application-packages> here
   ```

Does anyone had similar issue in the past ? If yes, could you please help me how I can fix this ?

Comment: See *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)* for instructions on formatting.

Comment: How do you configure the Jersey application?

Comment: I have a class that extended javax.rs.Application and it’s annotated ApplicationPath

Comment: Are you using the correct JAX-RS version, i.e. javax ad not Jakarta?